# unable to fetch results from search page while using ajax with checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font style="font-size:20px">Snp Id:</font>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="isnp_id" id="isnp_id" placeholder="Ex:SCcLG07_1001342" size=20 style="font-size:18px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font style="font-size:20px">Gene Id:</font>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="igene" id="igene" placeholder="Ex:C.cajan_17400" size=20 style="font-size:18px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font style="font-size:20px">Chromosome:</font>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ichr" id="ichr" placeholder="Ex:CcLG07" size=20 style="font-size:18px"></td>
      <td> position from </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="posstart" id="posstart" placeholder="Ex: 1" size="20"> to <input type="text" name="posend" id="posend" placeholder="Ex:100" size="20">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font style="font-size:20px">Genotype name:</font>
      </td>
      <td> <select style="font-size:18px" id="sg" name="sg">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="icpl_131">icpl_131</option>
    <option value="icpa_2039">icpa_2039 </option>
    <option value="icpl_96061">icpl_96061 </option>
     </select> </td>
      <td> between </td>
      <td> <select style="font-size:18px" id="sg2" name="sg2">
     <option  >Select</option>
     <option value="icpa_2039">icpa_2039 </option>
     <option value="icpl_131">icpl_131</option>
     <option value="icpl_96061">icpl_96061 </option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbc" id="cbc" value="cb_class" /> </td>
      <td>
        <font style="font-size:20px">Classification:</font>
      </td>
      <td><select style="font-size:18px" name="sclass" id="sclass">
     <option value="all" selected="selected">Select</option>
     <option value="intergenic">Intergenic</option>
     <option value="intronic">Intronic</option>
     <option value="non_synonymous_coding">Non Synonymous Coding</option>
     <option value="synonymous_coding">Synonymous Coding</option>
     </select> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbv" id="cbv" value="cb_vtype" /></td>
      <td>
        <font style="font-size:20px">Varation Type:</font>
      </td>
      <td><select style="font-size:18px" name="svtype" id="svtype">
      <option value="all" selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="snp">Snp</option>
      <option value="insertion">Insertion</option>
      <option value="deletion">Deletion</option>
      </select> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbf" id="cbf" value="cb_fc" /></td>
      <td>
        <font style="font-size:20px">Functional Class:</font>
      </td>
      <td><select style="font-size:18px" name="sfclass" id="sfclass">
        <option value="all" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="missense">Missense</option>
        <option value="nonsense">Nonsense</option>
        <option value="silent">silent</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" style="font-size:18px">
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="goto" value="Search" onclick="loadData('1')" style="font-size:18px"><span id="loadings"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Now jquery ajax function code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loading_show() {
    $('#loadings').html("<img src='js/loader2.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
  }

  function loading_hide() {
    $('#loadings').fadeOut('fast');
  }

  function loadData(page) {
    $('#tbl').hide();
    loading_show();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "newrs_old1.php",
      data: "page=" + page + "&isnp_id=" + $('#isnp_id').val() + "&igene=" + $('#igene').val() + "&ichr=" + $('#ichr').val() + "&posstart=" + $('#posstart').val() + "&posend=" + $('#posend').val() + "&sg=" + $('#sg').val() + "&sg2=" + $('#sg2').val() + "&cbc=" + $('#cbc').val() + "&sclass=" + $('#sclass').val() + "&cbv=" + $('#cbv').val() + "&svtype=" + $('#svtype').val() + "&cbf=" + $('#cbf').val() + "&sfclass=" + $('#sfclass').val(),
      success: function(msg) {
        $("#container1").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
          loading_hide();
          $("#container1").html(msg);
        });
      }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#goto').trigger('click');
      }
    });
    $(".reset").click(function() {
      $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
    });
    //loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
    $('#container1 .pagination li.active').live('click', function() {
      var page = $(this).attr('p');
      loadData(page);
    });
    $('#go_btn').live('click', function() {
      var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
      var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
      if (page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages) {
        loadData(page);
      } else {
        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and ' + no_of_pages);
        $('.goto').val("").focus();
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Without using jQuery and AJAX, search page is working well, when i started to use jquery and ajax to make it paginate ,checkbox creating issue here.
After implementation of ajax, input given in the search page is not taking by the script ,it is only taking checkbox values if checked.
I can get only checkbox based search results only ,remaining search columns are not working.
If i removed checkbox from ajax i can get remaining search column results. but i want both working because i am using combination search.
Plz help me to solve this issue. i dont know how to implement this issue in jquery ajax

Comment: checkbox should work if it is checked. by default it is checking for checkbox values due to ajax code which i given though it is unchecked, so input is not    getting executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using formdata to pass ajax something like

```
function SubmitForm() {
        var data = $("#yourform").serialize();
        var url = "Your URL"
        var form = $('#yourform')[0]
        var formdata = false;
        if (window.FormData) {
            formdata = new FormData(form);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formdata ? formdata : data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
//whatever
}
```

Comment: data: "page="+page+"&isnp_id="+$('#isnp_id').val()+"&igene="+$('#igene').val()+"&ichr="+$('#ichr').val()+"&posstart="+$('#posstart').val()+"&posend="+$('#posend').val()+"&sg="+$('#sg').val()+"&sg2="+$('#sg2').val()+"&cbc="+$('#cbc').val()+"&sclass="+$('#sclass').val()+"&cbv="+$('#cbv').val()+"&svtype="+$('#svtype').val()+"&cbf="+$('#cbf').val()+"&sfclass="+$('#sfclass').val(),

Comment: i have problem with line i think

Comment: yeah you are making things a bit complex by creating object in data prop instead of that create an object outside and pass that object as single data object

Comment: i am newbie in development, i will try my best to figure it out

Comment: i modified it according to ur suggestion now it is working fine, thank u

Answer (score 0):

just add unique id in you form tag like below

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" >
```

and get that form data using form id and pass in ajax like below

```
data: $('#form1').serialize();
```

serialize will pass all form field data in ajax.
you can get that data using $_POST